Postfix logs in ISO-short format on Ubuntu 24.04
I have a newly installed Ubuntu server (24.04) with Postfix. I set the Postfix log location which worked fine except all the date formats are in the following format:
Jun 06 18:03:45

But I want it to default to ISO:
2024-06-06 18:03:45

I tried the command:
journalctl -o short-iso

but this just seems to list the logs rather than setting anything.

https://serverfault.com/questions/967286/how-to-change-the-date-format-of-maillog

Thanks, I did see that post but I don't have a rsyslog.conf to edit.

Not a great answer but my workaround was to rotate the Postfix logs daily, which at least saved the files in yyyyMMdd format.
I did try and install the Rsyslog but between authenticated proxies and lack of knowledge it got corrupted, so that wasn't an option.
